# European pedal thread size

Tags: maintenance

Can North American pedals with a 9/16” x 20 TPI thread be used on a European rental bike or is there a metric requirement?

Answer (score 5):

Apart from special cases (IIRC one-piece cranks, really old french bicycles), the standard you mentioned is *the* universal pedal thread standard. So unless you specifically rent a bike with obsolete pedal standards, no technical reason will prevent you from using American pedals.
(You should obviously make sure that the owner of the bike is fine with changing the pedals!)